RL Model training
I trained a PPO algorithm using stablebaselines3, but when loading the model this happens
NotImplementedError: <class 'stable_baselines3.common.policies.ActorCriticCnnPolicy'> 
observation space is not supported

I tried running the code where I create the env how I did before training.
env = GrayScaleObservation(env, keep_dim= True) 
# Downsize frame quality 
env = ResizeObservation(env, shape=84) 
# Wrap inside dummy env 
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env]) 
# Stack Frames 
env = VecFrameStack(env, 4, channels_order= "last") 

model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, verbose= 1, tensorboard_log= LOG_DIR, learning_rate= 0.000001, 
            n_steps= 512 ) 

But nothing, same error
